# Copy Marketing Version and Build Version from Main App to extensions on Xcode 11

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode11

My app has several extensions that need to have the same marketing version. Before Xcode 11, my script would copy the values like this:

Marketing version: From within the extension build phase:

```
version=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleShortVersionString" "$SRCROOT/MyApp/Info.plist")

/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleShortVersionString $version" "$INFOPLIST_FILE"
```

Build Version: From within the main app build phase:

```
if [ "${CONFIGURATION}" = "Release" ] || [ "${CONFIGURATION}" = "Beta Release" ]; then
buildNumber=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleVersion" "$INFOPLIST_FILE")
buildNumber=$(($buildNumber + 1))

/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $buildNumber" "$INFOPLIST_FILE"
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $buildNumber" "$SRCROOT/Extensions/ActionExtension/Info.plist"
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $buildNumber" "$SRCROOT/Extensions/Siri Shortcuts/ViewTasksIntent/Info.plist"
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $buildNumber" "$SRCROOT/Extensions/Siri Shortcuts/ViewTasksIntentUI/Info.plist"
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $buildNumber" "$SRCROOT/Extensions/Siri Shortcuts/OP1TaskListIntent/Info.plist"

fi
```

But now since the version system is on the build settings instead of the plist, how can I do this ?

Comment: Hi, did you able to solve your issue?i have the same problem.

Comment: @Steven I ended up using agvtool in the pre-actions of my scheme, ditched the script in build phases